# Apps script authorization for openId don't work with onEdit(e) trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, oauth

I have a problem with a google sheet script, I would like to transfer data from one workbook to another using an onEdit trigger, but when my trigger fires, I have a message of error in the execution log which says that I do not have the authorizations to access this file, however when I do the same action but without trigger (by activating the function by hand) it works without problem. I don't know at all where the problem comes from, if someone can help me it would be really appreciated because I'm desperate (I found absolutely nothing on google after hours of research), thank you in advance for your help and have a nice day.
Joseph Menard
(PS; I am attaching a link to a video of my screen showing my problem ;
https://www.loom.com/share/f1a0fde043f74143b7caad78ae806be6 )

Comment: What Google quesry did you use, can you include it in your question. Have you tried searching by error text?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using a simple onEdit trigger? Simple triggers run without authorisation from the user and are subject to several [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions). Instead ty using an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) onEdit trigger and see if that helps?

Comment: Ok thanks for your advice, but i don't understand the difference between the simple and installable trigger, i readed the docs of google but i still don't understand.